# JAVA: Adding objects of type "Shape" in a ArrayList?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frdXr.png)Newbie_JAVA. Loving JAVA but I can't move forward since I am having trouble: 
To add in the ArrayList different objects.
Knowing that I have created a new ArrayList. Giving the size of my previous list to the new one. Getting the element at x index adding it to the new matching list index, and then increment until I reach the end of my List + One.

Comment: Welcome! It's a bit difficult to help without a bit of background with regards what you are trying to do. What have you already tried?  Where have you looked? Please see here for advice on asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @wobr thank you. I have edited my post to give people an overview about what I did.
All the posts that I have come across to are not taking in charge my case, I think.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Create an `ArrayList` from an `Array`? Why size+1?

Comment: @vicpermir I am trying to create an ArrayList type "Shape" and store every given shape in a array index. Here "shapes" is my array. Knowing that I have the list of the different shapes ready.
Correct me if I am wrong, I need to make sure that my List(type Shapes) and the new ArrayList have the same length + 1 for safety (as I used to do in C).

Comment: @Moukis Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have inside your question and not as an image, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors. Also, do you want to add the new shapes at the end of the existing list or do you want to "overwrite" the existing values with the new shapes? And if so, how do you want the case where one list is bigger/smaller than the other one? Please provide a [mcve] of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I fully understand what you are trying to do, but if your idea is that you populate a new arraylist using the items in the existing shapes array, this is the way to do it:

```
public void addShapes(Shape[] shapes) {
    //create an arraylist
    ArrayList<Shape> newList = new ArrayList();

    //loop over the shapes array and add every object in that array in the new arraylist
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        newList.add(shapes[i]);
    }
}
```